# Update LAMP stack

Tags: apt, updates, lamp

I have installed a **LAMP** stack using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`.
I would like to update its components versions to the latest. In particular PHP's version.

Is it possible to do via the **default (official)** repositories?
Or I have to compile it manually?